# Simple cross domain form posting not working (whmcs)

Tags: html, forms, .htaccess, post, whmcs

I am trying to get a search box to post its content into a searchbox on another domain, using the html post method, however its not working after being redirected to the second site the search box remains empty on site 2.

Both servers belong to the same business and I have access to both, can someone tell me what I could do without using java to get the contents from the input box 1 on site 1 posted to the input box 2 on site 2

here is the line of code I am using on the first site.

form action="https://site2.com/cart.php?a=add&domain" method="post"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You''ll need to catch and process both the GET arguments (in your action URL) and the POST stream (from the form elements) in the `site2.com/cart.php` file that you are using as the action.

Assuming the input box on site1 is named `inputBox` and is contained in the form with that action, when the form is submitted the `site2.com/cart.php` script can access the value at `$_POST['inputBox']` - ie, wherever that goes on site2, you could do

```
<form name="someformonsite2" action="....">
<input type=text 
<?php
  if((!empty($_POST['inputBox'])&&(passes_your_validation($_POST['inputBox']))){
    print("value=\"".$_POST['inputBox']."" );
  }
 ?> 
size=12 maxlength=11>
<!-- rest of form follows -->
```

Which would effectively send to the browser:

```
<input type=text value="SomeVal" size=12 maxlength=11>
```

Comment: Hi, I was hoping I could add some php code to the htaccess file to accept the post and leave the html forms as they are, is that possible.

Comment: I cannot get the php code to work directly in the file as its a whmcs file

Comment: @Davie well, shows me for thinking that `cart.php` might be written in php :)

Comment: Well it is but its encoded with ioncube and the php doesn't work in the templates file. Hope I can figure it out else I have a mess of a layout since the sites full of forms to be re posted to whmcs.

Comment: @Davie You can't add PHP code to the htaccess that just won't work, and as you've experienced you also can't add to the WHMCS core files (which you shouldn't do anyway) because they are encoded.  What you can do is utilize WHMCS' built in hooks. You can do almost anything using hooks you just need to know what hook to use and what you want to accomplish, here's the documentation to get you started https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks/getting-started/